# Was the folk song in the audition scene in "The Commitments" made for the movie?

Tags: soundtrack

In the [audition montage](https://youtu.be/xZLcZPb6FiI?t=179) in The Commitments, a young guy with a ponytail sings the following lyrics accompanied with a guitar and harmonica:

> Well, the black folks are starvin'
>
> And the white trash is carpin'
>
> And the KKK's all over the TV

It sounds like some kind of 60s folk song to me, but googling the lyrics turns up nothing but transcripts of the film. Was the song made for the movie? Does anyone know the origin of it, like who wrote it and the accompanying music?

Comment: Whilst this is perfectly acceptable here, you might have better luck at MusicFans.SE